# AHK for enter and arrow key

Tags: autohotkey

Can't seem to find this simple script anywhere. I'm trying to create a script that runs when the enter and right arrow key is pressed.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
{Enter}{Right}::
    Send, #tab
return
```

I know it must be something really simple but can't find the solution anywhere!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the documentation link for hotkeys:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm
And in there, after understanding the basics, you're interested in this part of it:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo

And assuming by `#tab` you mean pressing Windows key and the Tab key, you want to look at this page of the documentation:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm
(If you wanted to use the [`Send`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command, it'd be `Send, #{Tab}`)

You should end up with this:
`Enter & Right::#Tab` (have to press enter before right arrow key)
And that works, though you're probably going to want to add one little addition, which the [`~`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) modifier.
It'll make it so your <kbd>Enter</kbd> key also works on itself while the script is active.
So you'd end up with this:
`~Enter & Right::#Tab`

Though, now you'll always send a Enter keystroke every time you run the hotkey, which might not be good, I recommend switching it around to:
`~Right & Enter::#Tab`